# django model instance value set to none after the loop

Tags: django, django-models

Here, in the rename_dfs function, I am getting the Documents_details model instance and setting its corresponding fields inside the loop. Inside the for loop, some instance field values are getting set, but after the for loop, the instance field value automatically set to **None**.

```
def rename_dfs(documentId, request):
    doc_details = Documents_details.objects.get(id=documentId)

    for key, value in request.items():
        if request[key] and key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
            if re.search("_a$", key):
                doc_details.key = int(value)
                print(key, doc_details.key)

            if re.search("_b$", key):
                doc_details.key = int(value)
                print(key, doc_details.key)

    print(doc_details.document_date_a)

    doc_details.save()
```

Output:

```
document_date_a 7
invoice_no_a 5
invoice_type_a 3
narration_a 2
debit_credit_a 1

document_date_b 5
invoice_no_b 4
invoice_type_b 3
narration_b 2
debit_credit_b 1

None # last print statement after the loop
```

Model:

```
class Documents_details(models.Model):
    company_name_a = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    document_date_a = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    posting_date_a = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    invoice_no_a = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    invoice_type_a = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    narration_a = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    debit_a = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    credit_a = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    debit_credit_a = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    company_name_b = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    document_date_b = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    posting_date_b = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    invoice_no_b = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    invoice_type_b = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    narration_b = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    debit_b = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    credit_b = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    debit_credit_b = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    documents = models.ForeignKey(Documents, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `_b$`  will return a match where one of the specified character `_b` in end and in your case you are getting all match which ends with `_b`  but not `documents` because it din't contain `_b` in the end

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the right way to set attribute value dynamically, add the value is assigned to attribute `key`

It shall be

```
setattr(doc_details,key, int(value))
```